# How to display 'no result found' on search when there is no result found, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search page on my website that shows the products searched by the user. I want to display 'no products' to them if the products are not found in the database.

```
const searchKey = decodeURI(location.pathname.split('/').pop());
const searchResults = document.querySelector('.serach-results');

getMobile(searchKey).then(data => createMobileCards(data, '.mobile-card-container'));

if (!getMobile(searchKey).then(data => createMobileCards(data, '.mobile-card-container')).length) {
searchResults.innerHTML += 'no products';
```

}

but the code is not working!
If the there is no products found then it won't show anything.

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If `getMobile(searchKey)` is returning a promise you can't do `!getMobile(searchKey)`.

Comment: what do you mean with "not working" ? can you [edit] your question ?

Comment: if (getMobile(searchKey).then((data) => {if(createMobileCards(data, '.mobile-card-container')).length>0}) {
searchResults.innerHTML += 'no products';}
else{
createMobileCards(data, '.mobile-card-container')
}
})